# Calculate work load of my amazon mysql RDS instance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

How do I calculate work load of my amazon mysql RDS instance? Means my existing instance is capable to handle my uses load at pick time? and How to scale up this instance, if it is reached it's limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For RDS, the ability to change the instance is simple. I'll use the Console for the example.

Head over to the RDS Management Console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-west-1

Click on Instances, then select the Instance you wish to modify, right click or select the Instance Actions drop down menu towards the top and select Modify.

You can then change the size by selecting DB Instance Class. They are shown in order of size, ranging from Micro to Quadruple Extra Large (see http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-details for more details on each size)

Few other options there as well such as increasing the Allocate Storage and being provided with Provisioned IOPS.

The other one to look out for is the Apply Immediately checkbox which gives the option of making the changes you made take place right now rather than during the Maintenance Window you define.